# image recognition on android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I've been searching about this topic but i don't seem to find anything concrete on how to use image recognition on android. The app that i'm working on has a feature where it must extract circles of different sizes in an image with squares and triangles. I read that OpenCV is not completely suitable for Android. Is there any api that should know about? Some good links on the topic will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page **[here](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/msn/book/new_demo/houghCircles/)** has some sample Java code using the *[Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)* to find circles. Good luck!