# Android app that uses image recognition technology

Tags: android, opencv, image-recognition

I want to develop an android app that uses image recognition technology similar to Google googles. Since i'm new to image recognition technology, can anyone suggest which open source API can be used in Android to achieve this. I heard about OpenCV which can be used for this purpose, but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539400/image-recognition-on-android) says that openCV is not completely suitable for android. Is that so? Or this open source can be used for my specifications? Help me!

Comment: Goggles sends the image to a webservice and displays the result afaik. Your best bet is probably openCv but image recognition is quite a heavy task (cpu / memory) and may be too much for some phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV is perfectly suitable for Android. I'm working on a face recognition Android application with OpenCV and just completed the tutorials described in this link:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

The OpenCV 2.3.1 contains some samples and allows usage of C/C++ code as well by using a NDK for compilation. Check out this links as well:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk

Let me know if this helps you or when you need help setting up OpenCV with Android.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I will install as per the guide. Can you give me link for any tutorial where openCV is used in android with some example codes. It will be great help for me.

Comment: im using windows 7 OS. From your first link, under "get openCV for Android development" should i download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe/download) and follow the rest of the steps?

Comment: Yes the superpack in the downloadlink is fine. Just install/extract it anywhere on your disk but make sure the path has no spaces because those might generate errors. I just installed in **c:\opencv** This also generates a folder called samples/android/.. which you can use to fool around end experiment a bit. Just follow all steps in the tutorial links I provided and you will get these samples to work. To get the last 2 samples to work you need to follow the steps in the second download link I posted

Comment: i installed OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2 and unpacked it using 7-Zip. I imported the unpacked folders into eclipse. When i build, it's getting build, but i'm not able to see the /jni directory or /lib in the projects. Help me!

Comment: Relax mate, no worries ^^ You only need the /jni and /libs directories when you want to use an external .cpp file. Only the last 2 samples (tutorial-3-native & tutorial-4-native) requires these folders and you should see them when you open the samples projects. If you want to use a .cpp file read just follow the steps in the second link i posted. It tells you how to create these folders manually.

Comment: BTW you might want to fix a new question if you have more problems since more people might see your problem then. This one is tagged as answered

Comment: so to use the openCV API in my project i should follow the second link right? I followed the second link but there are build errors. I'm not able to see any errors in logcat window but a window pops up saying there are build errors. What should i do?

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you have now? Have you imported the samples projects by following the 1st tutorial and can you run the 15-puzzle for example? If there are build errors try right clicking on a project in the package explorer -> goto Android Tools -> then click on Fix Project Properties and they might disappear. Try to get the 15-puzzle sample to work first and let me know when you managed

Comment: yeah i imported the samples as mentioned in the first link. i'm getting the following errors when i run sample-15-puzzle. '[2012-03-28 17:02:27 - Sample - 15-puzzle] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
Origin 1: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android+openCV\samples\15-puzzle\bin\resources.ap_
Origin 2: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android+openCV\samples\15-puzzle\bin\classes\AndroidManifest.xml' this is the error in the logcat window. I'm using samsung galaxy ace,API version 8.0

Comment: Haven't been able to reply for a while, but how are you managing so far? Still need help? If so make a new topic and I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Google goggle has no exposed API as of today.

You can try iqengines. http://www.iqengines.com

It supports development on Android & IOS.

The drawback is -- It is not free. But it does offer a free trial.

Good Luck.